# Advanced Instagram-Api access for website

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am making my research for an upcoming project:

It is going to be a website you can login via your Instagram account - I need access to the user's name, profile picture and to the people he/she is following.

Is Instagram allowing a website/project to access this information?

Just in case this is a super easy question: I am not a developer and it is very hard for me to work through the Instagram developer website - I highly appreciate any help!!

Thank you very much!
Mathew

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to implement the [authentication](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) part, and receive an `access_token` for the user. In fact you will receive user's id, username, and profile photo along with the access_token.

That was the hardest part. Then you may use the `access_token` to make some API calls to get information such as `follows` and `followed-by`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Name, profile photo and followers using Instagram APIs.

Here are the 2 APIs you will need:

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_follows

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```